# MongoDB: update specific elements in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a documents with the following structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    "subjects": [
        {
            "name": "math",
            "first_try": {
                "passed": true
            },
            "second_try": {
                "passed": false
            },
            "third_try": {
                "passed": false
            },
            "fourth_try": {
                "passed": false
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

There are a couple of such subjects there.
Please don't suggest to change data structure, etc. - it's a fake data structure created just for this question (can't share original names, but structure is the same).

For each of these subjects I have always these 4 keys: "first_try", "second_try", ..., "fourth_try". Some of them are "passed", some - not.

For each subject I want to set `first_try.passed: true` if there weren't other passed tries.If for example `third_try.passed:true` I shouldn't update first_try.

I was trying to proceed with some `aggregate` conditions including `elemMatch` to find items for update, but it looks awful and didn't work as I expect.

Is it possible to handle this case with single `updateMany` query?

Comment: `first_try`, `second_try` etc. are objects or arrays? (you used brackets in the example but it looks like an object structure)

Comment: @sachav yes, they are objects. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

```js
collection.updateMany({}, 
  {$set: {"subjects.$[element].first_try.passed": true}}, 
  {arrayFilters: [{
      "element.first_try.passed":false,
      "element.second_try.passed":false,
      "element.third_try.passed":false,
      "element.fourth_try.passed":false}]})
```

Comment: So, it updates only for elements where all these cases are false, correct?

Comment: It will only update the elements where all the `*_try.passed` are false

Comment: What is `element` in your solution?

Comment: It's the identifier name, you can rename it